# Mastermind with duplicate pegs (editted only parts that matter)

Tags: java, project

Hi i have been coding for the classic mastermind game for a while. The program seems to work perfectly when there is no duplicate pegs.

```
public static void guessingNumber(int [] digits){
    print("Guess 5 digits numbers! ps.you only have 7 tries");
    boolean guess = true;
    int n = 0;
    while(guess){ n++;
    print("");
    print("Guess no." + n + "!");
    int [] yourGuess = manualNumber();
    int correctPosition = 0;
    int correctNumber = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<yourGuess.length; i++){
        if(digits[i] == yourGuess[i]){
            correctPosition += 1;
        } else if(contains(digits, yourGuess[i]) && digits[i] != yourGuess[i]){
            correctNumber += 1;
        }

    }
    print("You have " + correctPosition + " correct place and " + correctNumber + " correct numbers.");
    if(Arrays.equals(digits, yourGuess)){
        guess = false;
        print("");
        print("Well Done! You did it!");
        }
    else if(n==10){
        guess = false;
        print("");
        print("Game Over! You lose.");
    }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args){
showMainMenu();
selectMode();

}
}
```

What should i do next in order to allow duplicate pegs? Also, i need to write an algorithm for the cpu to guess my number. Suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

My realisation of Human vs CPU mode ( joke :) )

```
private static void runHumanVsCPU() {
    int[] digits = manualNumber();
    System.out.println("Guess no.1!\n"+digits[0]+digits[1]+digits[2]+digits[3]+digits[4]+"\nCPU have 5 correct place and 0 correct numbers.\n\nWell Done! CPU did it!");
}
```

P.S. Why "ps.you only have 7 tries" but

```
} else if (n == 10) {
    guess = false;
    print("");
    print("Game Over! You lose.");
}
```

?

Comment: well, i realised that 7 tries is not enough for 5 digits lol.